# Throttle or Ignore requests based on IP

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, rate-limiting

Is there something that I can use to set rules for Apache to throttle *temporarily* or ignore any IP address that makes X number of requests per second?

It would be great if there is an Apache module for this. I had a look at `mod_bandwidth` and `mod_limitipconn` but it seems they base things on bandwidth which is very hard for me to determine bandwidth in terms of number of requests per IP.

I would be happy to use something external to Apache that will work on a standard Linux server (Fedora or CentOS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iptables` has rate- and connection-limiting modules available:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m limit --limit X/second -p tcp --dport 80 --syn -j ACCEPT
```

Note that this won't actually limit the number of HTTP *requests*; it'll limit the number of TCP connections, which might not correspond to the number of HTTP requests if the browser is using keepalive.  Also note that most browsers will make a large number of parallel connections; you might want to use the `--limit-burst` option to make sure users don't get blocked by this behaviour.